# c++ write a stack method

Tags: c++, stack

I want to develop a function in C++ that will take two sorted stacks A and B (min on top), and, create one new stack that is merged and sorted (min on top).

It is only allowed to use minimum standard stack operations such as pop, push, size, and top.

For this task, no other data structure such as arrays are allowed.

The stack shall be implemented by a singly linked list, So, with a Stack class and a Node class.

I came up with the below attempt, which does not work.
The elements in the stack are in the wrong order.

```
Current output:  10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Expected Output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

How to do this correctly?

Please see my not working code below:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

// Node class for a minimum singly linked list
struct Node {
    int data{};     // Data part 
    Node* next{};   // Link
};

// Stack, implemented as singly linked list with only minimum necessary functions
class Stack {

    Node* head{};               // Head of singly linked list
    int numberOfElements{};     // Housekeeping. Stack size
public:
    Stack() {};                 // Default constructor. Do nothing
    // Convenience function. Build stack from initailizer list
    Stack(const std::initializer_list<int>& il) { for (const int i : il) push(i); }

    // And destructor, will release memory
    ~Stack() {
        Node* temp = head;          // Start with the head
        while (temp) {              // Iterate along the list
            Node* toDelete = temp;  // Remember Node that must be deleted
            temp = temp->next;      // Goto next element
            delete toDelete;        // Delete Remebered Element
        }
    }
    void push(const int value) {    // Push a new element onto the stack. Insert at  beginning
        Node* temp = new Node;      // Allocate memory for a new node
        temp->data = value;         // Assign data part to new Node
        temp->next = head;          // This will be the new head, so, next will point to previous head
        head = temp;                // Set head pointer to new Node
        ++numberOfElements;         // Bookkeeping, incremenent size
    }
    void pop() {                    // Simply dlete the first element in the linked list
        if (head) {                 // If there is something in the list at all
            Node* temp = head;      // Remember current head Node
            head = head->next;      // New head will be the current heads next node
            delete temp;            // Delete old head
            --numberOfElements;     // Bookkeeping, decremenent size
        }
    };
    int top() const { return head ? head->data : 0; }   // Simply retun data from head node
    int size() const { return numberOfElements; }       // expose size to outside world 

    void print() {                          // Helper for printing debug output
        Node* temp = head;                  // We will iterate over the list beginning at the head
        while (temp) {                      // As long as we are not at the end of the list
            std::cout << temp->data << ' '; // Show data
            temp = temp->next;              // And continue with next node
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

// This is the function that needs to be done
void mergeSortedStacks(Stack& s1, Stack& s2, Stack& merged) {
    
    // As long as there are elements in s1 or in s1
    while (s1.size() or s2.size()) {

        // If there are elements in both s1 and s2
        if (s1.size() and s2.size()) {

            // Which top element is smaller?
            if (s1.top() < s2.top()) {
                // S1 top is smaller. push on resulting output stack
                merged.push(s1.top());
                s1.pop();
            }
            else {
                // S2 top is smaller. push on resulting output stack
                merged.push(s2.top());
                s2.pop();
            }
        }
        // Only s1 has still some elements
        else if (s1.size()) {
            // Copy them to other stack
            merged.push(s1.top());
            s1.pop();
        }
        // Only s2 has still some elements
        else if (s2.size()) {
            merged.push(s2.top());
            s2.pop();
        }
    }
}
// Test
int main() {
    Stack s1{ 10, 8, 6, 4 ,2 };
    s1.print();
    Stack s2{ 9, 7, 5, 3, 1};
    s2.print();

    Stack m{};
    mergeSortedStacks(s1, s2, m);
    m.print();
}
```

Comment: No you don't have to write a stack and a list in C++ : C++ has `std::stack` and `std::list`. Writing your own list and stack will only lead you to the path of unitialized pointers and memory leaks. Just lookup all the questions on lists in C++ here on stackoverflow... there are hundreds. And all those people are learning datastructures using C++ (they are not learning C++)

Comment: Ok, this is the assignment. What di you try ? What issue did you encounter ? Which part are you struggling on ? Once you've done an honest attempt and if you have an issue at some point, then come back here, you'll have an actual question this time.

Comment: @PepijnKramer _"Writing your own list and stack will only lead you to the path of uninitialized pointers and memory leaks."_ Why ? I agree it's meaningless to do such a thing in C++ (except for learning datastructures mechanisms as you mentioned) but one can perfectly write a correct stack or list implementation in C++. If that wasn't the case, there would not be `std::stack` nor `std::list` available, and probably C++ wouldn't even exist neither :)

Comment: @Fareanor What I try to say is writing your own datastructures shouldn't be the first thing to do in C++. I've seen too many people struggling with them and running into problems and losing the "fun" of programming. It is a very useful skill to develop later.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I completely agree with that and, to be honest, I understood what you meant :) It was just that, as written, your claim could have been misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You idea is not bad.

Basically I would not change that much. Just reverse the values in the resulting stack. And this can simply be done with a temporary stack.

top/pop the elements from the one stack and then put it to the resulting stack. Thats all.

Please see:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

// Node class for a minimum singly linked list
struct Node {
    int data{};     // Data part 
    Node* next{};   // Link
};

// Stack, implemented as singly linked list with only minimum necessary functions
class Stack {

    Node* head{};               // Head of singly linked list
    int numberOfElements{};     // Housekeeping. Stack size
public:
    Stack() {};                 // Default constructor. Do nothing
    // Convenience function. Build stack from initailizer list
    Stack(const std::initializer_list<int>& il) { for (const int i : il) push(i); }

    // And destructor, will release memory
    ~Stack() {
        Node* temp = head;          // Start with the head
        while (temp) {              // Iterate along the list
            Node* toDelete = temp;  // Remember Node that must be deleted
            temp = temp->next;      // Goto next element
            delete toDelete;        // Delete Remebered Element
        }
    }
    void push(const int value) {    // Push a new element onto the stack. Insert at  beginning
        Node* temp = new Node;      // Allocate memory for a new node
        temp->data = value;         // Assign data part to new Node
        temp->next = head;          // This will be the new head, so, next will point to previous head
        head = temp;                // Set head pointer to new Node
        ++numberOfElements;         // Bookkeeping, incremenent size
    }
    void pop() {                    // Simply dlete the first element in the linked list
        if (head) {                 // If there is something in the list at all
            Node* temp = head;      // Remember current head Node
            head = head->next;      // New head will be the current heads next node
            delete temp;            // Delete old head
            --numberOfElements;     // Bookkeeping, decremenent size
        }
    };
    int top() const { return head ? head->data : 0; }   // Simply retun data from head node
    int size() const { return numberOfElements; }       // expose size to outside world 

    void print() {                          // Helper for printing debug output
        Node* temp = head;                  // We will iterate over the list beginning at the head
        while (temp) {                      // As long as we are not at the end of the list
            std::cout << temp->data << ' '; // Show data
            temp = temp->next;              // And continue with next node
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};


void mergeSortedStacks(Stack& s1, Stack& s2, Stack& merged) {
    
    Stack tempStack{};  // ****** New

    // As long as there are elements in s1 or in s1
    while (s1.size() or s2.size()) {

        // If there are elements in both s1 and s2
        if (s1.size() and s2.size()) {

            // Which top element is smaller?
            if (s1.top() < s2.top()) {
                // S1 top is smaller. push on resulting output stack
                tempStack.push(s1.top());
                s1.pop();
            }
            else {
                // S2 top is smaller. push on resulting output stack
                tempStack.push(s2.top());
                s2.pop();
            }
        }
        // Only s1 has still some elements
        else if (s1.size()) {
            // Copy them to other stack
            tempStack.push(s1.top());
            s1.pop();
        }
        // Only s2 has still some elements
        else if (s2.size()) {
            tempStack.push(s2.top());
            s2.pop();
        }
    }
    // Reverse stack *****
    const int stacksize = tempStack.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < stacksize; ++i) {
        merged.push(tempStack.top());
        tempStack.pop();
    }

}
// Test
int main() {
    Stack s1{ 10, 8, 6, 4 ,2 };
    s1.print();
    Stack s2{ 9, 7, 5, 3, 1};
    s2.print();

    Stack m{};
    mergeSortedStacks(s1, s2, m);
    m.print();
}
```

Comment: Detail, but I would not use an int as number of elements (since that should never be < 0 ), but rather std::size_t (like all containers do)